# React Native Image Position in container

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, native, positioning

I am trying to figure out how to precisely position an image in a  container in React Native.

Right now I have what is on the left, and I would like to be able to position the image like the example on the right. (and not justifying center as the part of the image I want to show is not necessarily the center of the image)

To be more clear what I want is to be able to re-position the part of the image that is showing. (ie: move it to the right but keeping it only taking up the same space)

and here is a snack:[snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/@digitalalien/imagetest)

[image: What I have][image: What I want]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, what you are looking for is `resizeMode` property.

> **resizeMode = "cover"**
>
> Scale the image uniformly so that both
>   dimensions of the image will be equal to or larger than the
>   corresponding dimension of the view.

---

Try this. Note that I added `resizeMode="cover"`.

```
<Image style={styles.image} resizeMode="cover" source={{uri: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg'}} />
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not it. Setting 'resizeMode: cover' is essentially the same as setting 'height:100%' (at least in this case they appear to function the same). 
What I want though is to be able to re-position the part of the image that is showing.

Answer (score 0):

So... I did find that I can get the result I want if I add:

**width: '170%'**

```
image:{
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    width: '170%'
  },
```

My assumption would be that this would stretch the image out but it just seems to re-position it. I am not sure why this behaves this way. I would think that there would be a better way to approach this problem but I haven't found anything.